# .NET Core/ SQL Server docker compose networking issue

Tags: .net, sql-server, docker-compose

I am new to docker, trying to connect .NET Core 3.0 Application with SQL database using docker-compose. 
I have defined the connectionstring in docker-compose.yml. 
I have tried with 127.0.0.1 with and without giving port(1433).

**This is the exception i am getting:**

```
webapi_1  | fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
webapi_1  |       An error occurred using the connection to database 'InstaDb' on server '127.0.0.1,1433'.
webapi_1  | fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
webapi_1  |       An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Insta.Infra.Data.Context.InstaDbContext'.
webapi_1  |       Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

**`docker-compose.yml`**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    webapi:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "5000:80"
        depends_on:
            - db
        environment:
            ConnectionStrings:InstaDBConnection: "Server=127.0.0.1,1433;Database=InstaDb;User=sa;Password=#Admin123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
    db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "#Admin123"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Insta.Mvc/Insta.Mvc.csproj", "Insta.Mvc/"]
COPY ["Insta.Infra.Data/Insta.Infra.Data.csproj", "Insta.Infra.Data/"]
COPY ["Insta.Application/Insta.Application.csproj", "Insta.Application/"]
COPY ["Insta.Domain/Insta.Domain.csproj", "Insta.Domain/"]
COPY ["Insta.Common.Utils/Insta.Common.Utils.csproj", "Insta.Common.Utils/"]
COPY ["Insta.Infra.IoC/Insta.Infra.IoC.csproj", "Insta.Infra.IoC/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Insta.Mvc/Insta.Mvc.csproj"
COPY . .

WORKDIR "/src/Insta.Mvc"
RUN dotnet build "Insta.Mvc.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Insta.Mvc.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

WORKDIR /src
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh

WORKDIR "/src/Insta.Mvc"
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Insta.Mvc.dll"]
```

Comment: Do you have SQL Server installed in the webapi container as well? Docker containers are essentially their own little Linux VM with `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` pointing to themselves. If you've published port 1433 of your db container have you tried using `Server=host.docker.internal,1433;` in your connection string instead? (Note: this only works for Docker Desktop, it won't work in a Docker production environment.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create networks with docker composes, where you can access other containers from a container via their domain names as well, like the following:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    webapi:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "5000:80"
        depends_on:
            - db
        environment:
            ConnectionStrings:InstaDBConnection: "Server=db,1433;Database=InstaDb;User=sa;Password=#Admin123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
        networks:
          - your-network
    db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "#Admin123"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
        networks:
          - your-network
  
networks:
    your-network:
        name: your-network
```

Notice that in the connection string you can use the name of the service as a host name.

Comment: Used networks now getting this exception
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "InstaDb" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'sa'.

Comment: tried changing SA_PASSWORD to MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD as well, but result is same

Comment: does the database actually exists, or does your application create it?

Comment: i am running dotnet ef update command in entrypoint.sh
it should generate the database itselft